# Adding a monitor to a multi-stage lead acid battery charger; charger never idles

Tags: charger, lead-acid

I have bought a cheap 24V multi-stages battery charger (Qili QL-09005-B2402000H) to charge two identical 12v lead acid gel batteries in series. I cannot link to the item because it's not available for sale anymore, but it was listed as "LotFancy 24V 2A Scooter Battery Charger". I know it starts charging at around 29v and then drops to 27.3v when going idle.

I designed a small monitor circuit that runs off the batteries while they're charging. At first, the charger didn't mind: it would fully charge the batteries at around 29v then switch to a floating voltage of about 27.3V after some time. Recently though, the charger began to get stuck charging at full voltage.

Now the batteries may have gone bad but they're not even one year old so I suspect my little monitor circuit is drawing too much current and the charger thinks the batteries (that aren't new anymore) still need charge. At least that's how I believe it works as I couldn't find anything useful info on the charger.

Is there a way to trick the charger into thinking the batteries are full? Or am I better off getting a charger that only does 27.3V idle charging (I wouldn't mind the extra charging time)? Or should I hack the charger and try to put the current sensor (if there's any) so it senses only the current going into the batteries? Or just cut off the charger after it's been charging for an hour straight and put it back on after an hour or so?

Note 1: The monitor needs to also run when there is no electricity. I thought of having the monitor on its own battery but it would need to be kept charged as well.

Note 2: I tried a single diode after the charger to subtract 0.4v at the batteries but it didn't do much.

Note 3: I've had an old APC ups that went bad once and its batteries litterally melted... Don't want that to happen again ;)

Comment: Provide a separate power supply for your monitor so it doesn't cause the charger to stay in the charging phase.

Comment: The monitor needs to also run when there is no electricity. I thought of having the monitor on its own battery but it would need to be kept charged as well. I'll update the question with that detail. Thanks though.

Comment: have a couple of diodes so that it normally has it's own power supply (when charging) and is powered from the battery when you lose power. By definition  the battery won't be charging then.

Comment: What is the stuck voltage, everything may be OK, just the batteries aging. Link into Battery University, they have a lot of great information on batteries.

Comment: How much current does your monitor draw?

Comment: The monitor draws ~40 mA with screen and sensors. The question is about a stripped down version of the actual project, for clarity. The actual project spans multiple pages of schematics. I found the problem: the monitor didn't actually draw too much power, but another part of the system did because of a relay that got its contacts burned from too much surge current. Apparently the contacts of a 8A relay does not like to directly feed thousands of µF worth of capacitors. So the problem indeed was too much current drawn, but not because of the monitor. You got me searching in the right place.

Comment: While taking measurements, I believe I saw the charger switch to its charge mode at around 1A. Plenty of room.

Answer (score 1):

*What* does your "small monitor circuit" actually DO? Can you share its circuit diagram, and exactly where you're connecting it to the 2xLA batteries?  What is it measuring (V? I? Temp?), and how much power does it consume?

Is it powered from the 24V (2 batteries in series), or only from 1 of the batteries?  If your monitor circuit is "12V" and getting its power from just 1 of the 2 batteries, and if it draws a "significant" amount of power, then you're unequally discharging the batteries, and pushing closer toward the possibility of one battery becoming deeply discharged and the other not, and thus during recharge one of them reaches 100% full much sooner than the other (powering the monitor cct) so it can become over-charged and be damaged that way.

A decently designed 'monitor' circuit drawing power equally from both batteries (i.e. 24V) shouldn't prevent the charger from charging, nor from reaching full charge and going into float-charge stage, unless your meter really was sucking a lot of power (i.e. is it a Raspberry Pi project? lol).

HOWEVER, misuse of LA batteries is way more common that most amateurs realise.  If you're in the habit of deeply discharging this battery pair, then they could easily fail in 1 year, just depends on how deeply you discharge, how often you do that, and what the battery's specs advise for in-warranty use.

There are a few different types of lead-acid batteries.  Some are intended for 'backup' use, like in a UPS, where discharges are infrequent; if you discharge them a lot (even not deeply) they will degrade very quickly.  There are other LA designs that are referred to as 'deep cycle' which cope with deeper discharges better, but we're still only talking about ~50% depth-of-discharge (i.e. if your LA battery has a 10A.h capacity, using *more* than 5 A.h of its capacity *regularly* WILL result in premature death of the battery.  True story.  Lead-Acid batteries are NOT at all like much more modern Lithium-Ion chemistry batteries which can handle near-full depth-of-discharge excursions much better.

Comment: Thanks for the detailes answer. The monitor is powered from the batteries in series (24V). There's nothing inbetween the batteries other than a fuse. The batteries are kept charged most of the time and pretty much never gets discharged as low as 50%. The monitor is a ATMEGA328 based project with a couple of sensors here and there to measure voltage at the battery and the batteries temperature. There's also an oled screen that's kept off most of the time. I'll take a measurement for how much current it draws.

Comment: The monitor system including the screen and the sensors draw about 40mA. Thanks to your answer and the comments on the question, I got to take some measurements at the right place and I found the problem. Please see my comment in the original question. Thanks for your detailes answer.

Answer (score 0):

This specific charger seems to switch from 27.3V idle to 29V charging at around 1A. Anything below that and the charger idles.

My monitor circuit draws around 40mA which should not trigger the charger. However, I had another circuit that drew significantly more because of a bad design. Anyway, I think a battery monitor can safely be added after a charger, as long as it draws very little current so not to interfere.

Now like Techydude has mentionned, there are many different types of acid batteries. Quality ones most likely come with a datasheet, and the floating voltage and current should be in there. I got a cheap charger that should fit the bill for most batteries but I'd say a well designed one should be adjustable to fit a battery specific specs, and allow for some more current to provide any monitor ;)